# Swing UI Refresh: Background thread prints exception

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have Jframe in which I 'm displaying JTree. Since I have large number of nodes to be added what I did is created 4 threads that keep on adding node to Tree.

To make newly added nodes visible on UI. I reload frame every 10 seconds using,

```
SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
```

My Frame gets reloaded and newly added nodes are visible now. But there is background thread that prints exception on my console. Although it does not hinder my UI output. But can I know the reason, cause of below exception and how can I get rid of that

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.layoutHScrollbar(BasicScrollBarUI.java:731)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.layoutContainer(BasicScrollBarUI.java:833)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)




Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollPaneUI.paint(BasicScrollPaneUI.java:90)
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(ComponentUI.java:143)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(JComponent.java:752)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1029)



Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.layoutVScrollbar(BasicScrollBarUI.java:638)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicScrollBarUI.layoutContainer(BasicScrollBarUI.java:829)
    at java.awt.Container.layout(Container.java:1421)
    at java.awt.Container.doLayout(Container.java:1410)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1507)
    at java.awt.Container.validateTree(Container.java:1513)
```

Also, exception stack trace changes as you can see above. I'm not able to figure out what is possible cause for that. I also synchronized the code so that no new nodes are added while frame is getting refreshed. But it didn't help.

Please advise what should I do in such case.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing is not thread-safe. All modifications to Swing UI components need to be performed from the event dispatch thread. You should remove the four threads that you have implemented and perform all operations from the main thread.

Comment: I tried to execute it via main(). Also, I tried using SwingUtilities.invokeLater(). But exception seems to be coming

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){

     public void run() {
                SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);
      
     }}
    );